# Clear all fields after record inserted in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a small form of 4 fields, I am using Ajax to save record and give alert to user on same page. all is working fine but I want to clear all 4 fields after record is inserted and don't want user to press again and duplicate,

Right now I am using

```
this._studentName.text = "";
```

but is there any easy method to get same result coz I have another form where there are more then 40 fields and don't want write .text = "" 40 times

Comment: Why don't you look at using `jQuery` to do this client side? How are you doing AJAX presently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery then you could write:

```
$('#formID input[type=text]').val('');
```

If you don't use jQuery then you could still call `this.getElementsByTagName('input')` and loop through the results to clear the values.

Answer (score 1):

If it's applicable, Why not redirect to the same page? :)